# Replicate CommunityGraphPlot as a Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is it possible to format a `Graph` object in a similar way to `CommunityGraphPlot`, but retain it as a `Graph`?  I've been playing with `FindGraphCommunities` but I'm obviously missing some of the pre-processing that `CommunityGraphPlot` does.

Ideally I'd like a `Graph` formatted like `CommunityGraphPlot` but still easily manipulatible wrt to the right-click options that graph offers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take the example from the [`CommunityGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommunityGraphPlot.html) documentation,

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}]
CommunityGraphPlot@g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At first I thought I would try to replicate what `CommunityGraphPlot` is doing, using the information from `FindGraphCommunities`

```
HighlightGraph[g, Map[Subgraph[g, #] &, FindGraphCommunities@g]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But that isn't right, we want to separate out the different communities more, to highlight them better.  So on to plan 2: let `CommunityGraphPlot` do the hard work, and take the coordinates from it.  If you look at the `InputForm` for a `CommunityGraphPlot` you see a bunch of `Disk` objects, and the are conveniently in the same order as the vertices.  So we can feed them to the `VertexCoordinates` option.

```
HighlightGraph[
 SetProperty[g,
  {VertexCoordinates -> 
    Cases[CommunityGraphPlot@g, Disk[a__, b_] :> a, Infinity]}],
 Map[Subgraph[g, #] &, FindGraphCommunities@g]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now that is *really* close to what we want, but all those blue lines between communities really make it ugly.  So we need to extract the curves between communities and the lines within a community, and create an `EdgeShapeFunction` from them.

One method is to use `Trace` to find out what `EdgeShapeFunction` is being called (For this I'll use a much simpler example that only has 2 curvy lines)

```
Trace[CommunityGraphPlot@GridGraph[{3, 2}], 
    HoldPattern[EdgeShapeFunction -> _List], TraceInternal -> True] //
    Flatten // DeleteDuplicates // ReleaseHold
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This tells us how we need to structure the `EdgeShapeFunction`.  We can extract the `"ControlPoints"` from the `Graphics` output of `CommunityGraphPlot`.

Now we can wrap it all up in a function

```
communityGraphGraph[g_Graph, options : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{cgp, gcomm, pts, curves, curveToEdgeFunc}, 
  cgp = Normal@CommunityGraphPlot@g;
  pts = Cases[cgp, Disk[a__, b_] :> a, Infinity];
  curves = curves = Cases[cgp, BezierCurve[__], Infinity][[All, 1]];
  gcomm = FindGraphCommunities@g;
  curveToEdgeFunc[curve_] := 
   First@Select[EdgeList@g, 
      Sort[List @@ #] === 
        Sort@Extract[VertexList@g, 
          Position[pts, 
           First@curve | Last@curve]] &] -> {"GroupBundlingEdge", 
     "ControlPoints" -> curve[[2 ;; -2]], "Opacity" -> Automatic};
  HighlightGraph[
   SetProperty[
    g, {VertexCoordinates -> pts, 
     EdgeShapeFunction -> (curveToEdgeFunc /@ curves)}],
   Map[Subgraph[g, #] &, gcomm], options
   ]
  ]
```

Here is what it looks like for the graph above,

```
communityGraphGraph@
 ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One could go a step further and add the circles around the communities by using an `Epilog` option, and the head would still be `Graph`.  Personally I like the look without the circles, where the edges within a community are colored alike.

Compare the output of this function with the built-in that we are trying to emulate

```
{communityGraphGraph[GridGraph[{7, 7}], ImageSize -> 500, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"],
 CommunityGraphPlot[GridGraph[{7, 7}], ImageSize -> 500, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]}
Head /@ %
```

[image]

Here is another example from the documentation,

```
communityGraphGraph[
 ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}], ImageSize -> 700,
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Star"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you can find a graph that breaks this function, please let me know.

### Addendum

Another way to write the function would be to just extract the `EdgeShapeFunction` directly from the `Trace` output.  This version is a bit shorter, and is pasted [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/d4e8dc1be7ed959b28f2a62ca9cb96b7/raw/afdbe369d645a9d91c9022db9855cd7c03853bab/gistfile1.txt).

Comment: Splendid thank you!

Comment: For that case, it works to just use `communityGraphGraph[
 ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Star"]`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Extracting the Graph object

An alternative way of using `Trace` to extract the `Graph` object and vertex coordinates:

```
ClearAll[communityGraphF]
communityGraphF = ReleaseHold[First[Flatten[Trace[CommunityGraphPlot[#, ##2],
  GraphComputation`GraphDrawing[gr_, vc_, __] :> SetProperty[gr, {vc, Options[#]}], 
 TraceInternal -> True]]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
zkc = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}];
Row[{CommunityGraphPlot[zkc, ImageSize -> 500], communityGraphF[zkc, ImageSize -> 500]}]
```

[image]

```
dsn = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}];
Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold[#[dsn, ImageSize -> 600]], Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
 {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphF]}]
```

[image]

#### Highlighting within-community edges

```
ClearAll[communityGraphF2, eS]
eS[g_] := Module[{ghS = PropertyValue[{g, #}, GraphHighlightStyle] &}, 
  If[SameQ[ghS[#], ghS[#2]], VertexStyle /. ghS[#], Gray]] &;

communityGraphF2 = ReleaseHold[First[Flatten[Trace[CommunityGraphPlot[#, ##2], 
  GraphComputation`GraphDrawing[gr_, vc_, __] :> SetProperty[gr, {vc, Options[#], 
   EdgeStyle -> {UndirectedEdge[u_, v_] :> eS[gr][u, v]}}], TraceInternal -> True]]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold[#[zkc, ImageSize -> 500]], Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
 {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphF2]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold[#[dsn, ImageSize -> 500]], Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
 {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphF2]}]
```

[image]

#### Extracting the blobs and the labels

To get the blobs and labels we need a few more lines:

```
communityGraphFwBlobs = Module[{blobsandlabels = 
   DeleteDuplicates[ReleaseHold[Flatten@Trace[CommunityGraphPlot[##], 
    _[GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`blobsgraphics |
      GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`labelgraphics, b_] :> b, 
   TraceInternal -> True]] /. {{} -> Sequence[], Graphics[x_, ___] :> x }]}, 
  ReleaseHold[First[Flatten[Trace[CommunityGraphPlot[#, ##2], 
    GraphComputation`GraphDrawing[gr_, vc_, __] :> 
     SetProperty[gr, {vc, Options[#], Prolog -> blobsandlabels}], 
   TraceInternal -> True]]]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
opts = Sequence[VertexLabels -> "Name", CommunityRegionStyle -> 63, 
   CommunityLabels -> (Style[#, 18] & /@ {"one", "two", "three"}), 
   BaseStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], ImagePadding -> 15, ImageSize -> 500];


Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold@#[zkc, opts], Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
  {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphFwBlobs]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold@#[dsn, 
   CommunityLabels -> (Style[#, 18] & /@ {"one", "two", "three", "four"}), 
   ImageSize -> 600, opts], Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
 {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphFwBlobs]}]
```

[image]

With an exogenously given community structure as the second argument:

```
Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold[#[zkc, Partition[VertexList[zkc], 10, 10, 1, {}], opts]], 
  Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@
 {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphFwBlobs]}]
```

[image]

Input graph may have non-default `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
zkc2 = SetProperty[zkc, {VertexSize -> 1.5, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[16, White, Bold], 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "ConcaveHexagon"}];

Row[Labeled[ReleaseHold@#[zkc2, 
  CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; 3]]),
  ImageSize -> 500], Style[#, 20, "Panel"], Top] & /@ 
 {HoldForm[CommunityGraphPlot], HoldForm[communityGraphFwBlobs]}]
```

[image]