# CommunityGraphPlot colors the communites automatically. Is it possible to access a list of those colors, ordered by community?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, color

I have some code (see below) that takes a large graph and recursively coarse-grains it by modular community structure. Each step takes a graph as input, detects its communities, coarse-grains the communities into single effective nodes and then outputs a graph of these effective nodes. I attach an image that shows the input and detected communities for each step.[image: Problem]

I would like to be able to map the colors of the communities at each step to the effective nodes created from them. So, the nodes in the third graph in the image would be coloured to match the communities in the second graph, from which they are created. How can I do this?

```
(*Define functions*)
adjacencylist = Module[{g = #}, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ EdgeList[g]] &;
CL[a_, b_] := If[b < a, Floor[b], Ceiling[b]]

(*Recursively renormalize graph*)
G = RandomGraph[{300, 2000}];
GL = {G};
GCL = {};
k = 1;

While[Length[adjacencylist[GL[[k]]]] > 1, GL = Append[GL,
   
(*Find graph communities*)
   GC = FindGraphCommunities[GL[[k]], Method -> "Modularity"];
   (*Identify links within and between communities*)
   
   LWBC = 
    Table[
     Select[adjacencylist[GL[[k]]], 
      MemberQ[GC[[i]], #[[1]]] && MemberQ[GC[[j]], #[[2]]] || 
        MemberQ[GC[[j]], #[[1]]] && MemberQ[GC[[i]], #[[2]]] &], {i, 
      1, Length[GC]}, {j, 1, Length[GC]}];

   (*Actual numbers of links within and between communities*)
   nLWBC = 
    Table[
     Length[LWBC[[i, j]]], {i, 1, Length[LWBC]}, {j, 1, Length[LWBC]}];

   (*Max possible number of links within and between communities*)
   LBCmax = 
    Table[
     Length[GC[[i]]] Length[GC[[j]]], {i, 1, Length[GC]}, {j, 1, 
      Length[GC]}];

   (*Link occupation between communities*)
   LO = nLWBC/LBCmax - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[nLWBC/LBCmax]] // N;
   
(*Coarse grain link occupations (0 if < mean, 1 if > 
   mean) and create resulting graph object*)
   G1 = AdjacencyGraph[
     Outer[
       CL, {Mean@
          Flatten@Delete[LO, Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, Length[GC]}]] // N},
        LO] // First]
   ]; GCL = Append[GCL, GC]; k++]

(*Graph populations at each level are*)
Pop = 
 Length /@ VertexList /@ GL
(*Show graph list*)
GL;
GCLP = Table[
   CommunityGraphPlot[GL[[i]], GCL[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[GCL]}];
GGCL = Append[
  Flatten[Table[{GL[[i]], GCLP[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[GCL]}]], Last[GL]]
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) of the code you are using to generate and coarse-grain the graphs.

Comment: Do you want [`FindGraphCommunities`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGraphCommunities.html)?  [This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77802/9490) might be helpful as well.

Comment: @Domen, I've added the code.

Comment: @JasonB. I'm ok with finding the communities but I don't know how to identify the colors that they've been assigned by the plotting function. If I could get a list of those colors, with the same order as the communities, I'd be set.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146066/12 You can provide your own colours, e.g. from `ColorData[97] /@ Range[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Szabolcs' comment (thanks!), I was able to come up with the following, which does what I need.

```
(*Define functions*)
adjacencylist = Module[{g = #}, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ EdgeList[g]] &;
CL[a_, b_] := If[b < a, Floor[b], Ceiling[b]]
CommunityColors = 
  GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList;

(*Recursively renormalize graph*)
G = RandomGraph[{500, 4000}];
GL = {G};
GCL = {};
k = 1;
While[Length[adjacencylist[GL[[k]]]] > 1, GL = Append[GL,

   (*Find graph communities*)
   GC = FindGraphCommunities[GL[[k]], Method -> "Modularity"];

   (*Identify links within and between communities*)
   LWBC = 
    Table[
     Select[adjacencylist[GL[[k]]], 
      MemberQ[GC[[i]], #[[1]]] && MemberQ[GC[[j]], #[[2]]] || 
        MemberQ[GC[[j]], #[[1]]] && MemberQ[GC[[i]], #[[2]]] &], {i, 
      1, Length[GC]}, {j, 1, Length[GC]}];

   (*Actual numbers of links within and between communities*)
   nLWBC = 
    Table[
     Length[LWBC[[i, j]]], {i, 1, Length[LWBC]}, {j, 1, Length[LWBC]}];

   (*Max possible number of links within and between communities*)
   LBCmax = 
    Table[
     Length[GC[[i]]] Length[GC[[j]]], {i, 1, Length[GC]}, {j, 1, 
      Length[GC]}];

   (*Link occupation between communities*)
   LO = nLWBC/LBCmax - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[nLWBC/LBCmax]] // N;
  
 (*Coarse grain link occupations (0 if < mean, 1 if > 
   mean) and create resulting graph object*)
   G1 = AdjacencyGraph[
     Outer[
       CL, {Mean@
          Flatten@Delete[LO, Table[{i, i}, {i, 1, Length[GC]}]] // N},
        LO] // First]
   ]; GCL = Append[GCL, GC]; k++]

(*Graph populations at each level are*)
Pop = 
 Length /@ VertexList /@ GL

(*Output graphics*)
CT = Table[
   Thread[GCL[[i, j]] -> CommunityColors[[j]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[GCL]}, {j, 1, Length@GCL[[i]]}];
GL;
GCLP = Table[
   CommunityGraphPlot[GL[[i]], GCL[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[GCL]}];
GLCM = Table[
   GraphPlot[GL[[i + 1]], VertexSize -> Medium, 
    VertexStyle -> 
     Table[j -> CT[[i, j, 1, 2]], {j, 1, Pop[[i + 1]]}]], {i, 1, 
    Length[GCL]}];
GGCL = Prepend[
  Flatten[Table[{GCLP[[i]], GLCM[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[GCL]}]], 
  First[GL]]
```

Here's an example of the output. The colors now map from communities to coarse-grained nodes, which are then recolored in the next step according to the next level of community detection. I also played with the vertex size, to help clarify that the coarse-grained nodes represent communities.

[image]